# Connect a Zywall USG200 to Windows Server 2012R2 based IPSEC/l2tp VPN

Tags: vpn, ipsec, l2tp, zywall

I'm trying to build a network configuration where clients can connect to some servers in a VPN via a Zywall USG 200 router/firewall.

[the network schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGgmI.png)

The architecture is composed by a windows server 2013 that acts as VPN gateway and some other servers connected directly to it via IPSEC/l2tp with PSK. Some computers in a LAN should be able to connect to these servers without connect directly to the VPN itself. To my somewhat limited networking knowledge this could be accomplished by connecting the Zywall to the VPN and then setup some routing (and firewall) rules to enable the clients to reach the VPN network.

What I'm failing to accomplish at the moment, It's how to connect the Zywall as client in the VPN. There are [plenties of guides](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r26985207-L2TP-VPN-on-USG-quick-how-to) on how to setup the Zywall as a IPSEC/l2tp gateway, but I found none that explains my configuration. From the Zywall USG200 manual I found out how to configure an IPSEC VPN, but I don't understand how to configure the L2TP tunnel. The L2TP page on the Zywall configuration seems used to configure a L2TP "server" ("L2TP Network Server"? I'm a bit confused about nomenclature here) and not the connection to an existing L2TP "server".

Comment: Could you include the graphic directly in this post?  Links can break/go stale, which would mean loss of context for this question.

Comment: @Castaglia the image is uploaded on stackexchange and included in the post as an image. I have to low rep on serverfault for it to be displayed inline.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand a zywall at both end if you can. (Your question is almost a duplicate of that [one](https://serverfault.com/questions/573994/site-to-site-ipsec-vpn-between-server-2012-and-usg-50) by the way)

For your question please see [there](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2014/12/26/vpn-interoperability-guide-for-windows-server-2012-r2/) for a guide, and some link. (zywall is not wrote).

To see some example to configure the zywall to other type network gear to make a site to site vpn, there is some resources ([there](http://www.zyxel-tech.de/snotezw5_362/app/zw_cisco.htm) and [there](ftp://ftp.zyxel.it/guide/usg/guide_next_gen_usg_firmware_4/next_gen_usg_vpn_ipsec_site_to_site_ms_azure.pdf)).

With both links I gave you can see a zywall <==> cisco tunnel, and a microsoft <==> cisco tunnel's example, so it should give you an actual idea of what to do. (As zywall did not wrote that KB for a zywall <==> microsoft tunnel)

> Introduction
>
> Microsoft® Windows® Server 2012 R2 industry standard IKEv2 tunnel for
>   VPN connectivity (both point-to-site and site-to-site). This enables
>   customers with existing third party VPN devices to easily deploy the
>   Windows Server 2012 R2 VPN gateway and interoperate with these devices
>   to perform branch-site networking.
>
> This document covers the working configurations for some of the
>   popular third party VPN devices that can be deployed to work with
>   Windows Server 2012 R2 VPN. The configuration for a Windows gateway is
>   also included to server as a guideline for an interoperable deployment
>   with the third party devices. Windows Server Gateway
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 gateway can be configured for point-to-site
>   (P2S) VPN, site-to-site (S2S) VPN, dynamic BGP Routing or a
>   combination of these features. The P2S VPN support and its
>   interoperability on the Windows Server 2012 R2 remains unchanged and
>   the details are available here. The dynamic BGP Routing support is the
>   implementation of standard BGP4 protocol. This enables the dynamic BGP
>   routing to be configured between the Windows gateway and the secondary
>   branch site (provided the site is using a Windows or a third party
>   BGP4 router).
>
> **> To establish a S2S VPN connection between a multi-tenant Windows
>   Server 2012 R2 VPN gateway and your third party device, you will have
>   to make sure the third party device supports IKEv2 tunnelling protocol
>   and that the IPSec parameter configuration is compatible to that of
>   the Windows configuration. IPSec Configuration**
>
> This section lists the various IPSec configuration parameters for
>   IKEv2 tunnel available on the Windows Server 2012 R2 S2S VPN Gateway.
>   Configuration via SC-VMM
>
> Configuration via SC-VMM offers even more customizable IPSec
>   configuration options like can be seen in this VM Network Properties
>   window (SC-VMM > VM and Service > VM Networks > Tenant Network >
>   Properties)
>
> Figure 1: SC-VMM VPN connection configuration
>
> We have validated a set of standard third party S2S VPN devices in for
>   interoperability with Windows Server 2012 R2 VPN gateway. These
>   compatible devices are listed below along with the example
>   configuration for these device families to help configure your VPN
>   device.
>
> If you don’t see your device in the known compatible VPN device list
>   and want to use the device for your VPN connection, you’ll need to
>   verify that it meets the minimum requirements outlined in the previous
>   section. Devices meeting the minimum requirements should also work
>   well with Windows Server 2012 R2 Gateway.
>
> Vendor
>
> Device Family
>
> OS Version
>
> Example configuration
>
> CheckPoint
>
> Security Gateway
>
> R75.40
>
> R75.40VS
>
> Configuration instructions
>
> Cisco
>
> ASA 5500 series
>
> ASA v9.0 (3)
>
> Device Manager v 7.1(2)
>
> [View:~/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-55-08/Cisco-ASA-5510-config.txt:50:50]
>
> Cisco
>
> ASR
>
> IOS 15.2
>
> Cisco ASR templates
>
> Cisco
>
> ISR
>
> IOS 15.1
>
> Cisco ISR templates
>
> Fortinet
>
> FortiGate
>
> FortiOS 5.0.7
>
> Configuration instructions
>
> Juniper
>
> SRX series
>
> JunOS 11.4
>
> Juniper SRX templates
>
> Juniper
>
> SRX series
>
> JunOS 12.1
>
> [View:~/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-55-08/Juniper-SRX100-config.txt:50:0]
>
> Juniper
>
> J-Series
>
> JunOS 11.4
>
> Juniper J-series templates
>
> Juniper
>
> ISG
>
> ScreenOS 6.3
>
> Juniper ISG templates
>
> Juniper
>
> SSG
>
> ScreenOS 6.2
>
> [Juniper SSG templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn133796.aspx)

If you opt for a zywall at both end, there how I see it, and the official guide to do it by zywall [there](http://kb.zyxel.com/KB/searchArticle!gwsViewDetail.action?articleOid=010530&lang=EN).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the whole bag of documentation, some of the stuff seems promising. But i don't understand what would the beneficts of a zywall-to-zywall vpn be. If this thing can work as intended, with the WS2013 server as vpn gateway, I intend to make it work that way. If it can't, i will consider other options (OpenVPN on a linux server maybe). I can see no inherent benefit in using another Zywall as VPN gateway in the described scenario.